# xml to xsd conversion problem

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML i want to validate in java.

The only problem i have left is trying to write the XSD for an attribute which is actually a reference to a namespace.
It's not possible to use the "<xs:attribute name="xmlns"/>" because xmlns is not allowed as the name of an attribute.
Any ideas?

**XML**:

```
<header>        
<abc xmlns="www.example.org">
<user>me</user>               
</abc>
</header>
```

**XSD**:

```
<xs:element name="header">
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:sequence>  
 <xs:element name="abc">  
 <xs:complexType>   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string" />      
 </xs:sequence>  
 </xs:complexType>  
 </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I don't think that I understand what you are trying to do here.  Is the xsd supposed to somehow force the document to declare a particular namespace?

Comment: I need to know what the XSD should be in order for the XML to validate. i don't care what the XML represents it's always hard coded in the same way. I can't seem to write an XSD that has no warnings because of this namespace attribute

Answer (score 1):

The **header** element doesn't have a namespace declared, so it gets the "unnamed namespace".  The *xmlns* attribute in the **abc** element declares the namespace as www.example.org (without a namespace prefix). The "user" element is actually in the **www.example.org** namespace, since it is a child of the "**abc**" element, which has a declared namespace (*xmlns="www.example.org*).

Neither sets of elements are using namespace prefixes to disambiguate the two "types" of elements, so it is a little confusing when you look at them.  It might be more clear if you were to use a namespace prefix for the ***www.example.org*** namespace in your XML, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<header xmlns:example="www.example.org">        
    <example:abc >
        <example:user>me</example:user>               
    </example:abc>
</header>
```

The XML above and the XML that you posted are equivalent, but it is a little easier to understand which elements "belong" to the "***www.example.org***" namespace when you use a namespace prefix.

The [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com) schema generation utility produced two schemas(below) that import each other.

**Your sample XML document validates against these schemas**(since they both import each other, you can reference either one when you call your validation)

First Schema file ***sampleSchema.xsd***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:ns1="www.example.org">
  <xs:import namespace="www.example.org" schemaLocation="example.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="header">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:abc"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Second Schema file ***example.xsd***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="www.example.org" xmlns:ns1="www.example.org">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="sampleSchema.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="abc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:user"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="user" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

'xmlns' is reserved as by [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl).

Edit: If you want certain elements to belong to a namespace, you must use this namespace in your schema, too.

Comment: I need to know what the XSD should be in order for the XML to validate.
i don't care what the XML represents it's always hard coded in the same way.
I can't seem to write an XSD that has no warnings because of this namespace attribute.